# Filtering a single column with OR operator

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Would like to do filtering in kendo grid within the same column for getting a union of values coming from a multiselect field:

```
$('#btnSearchRoles').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //process searched roles
        var multiselect = $("#RoleSubroleId").data("kendoMultiSelect");
        // get data items for the selected options.
        var dataItem = multiselect.dataItems();
        var filterCode = "[";
        for (var i = 0; i < dataItem.length; i++) {
            filterCode += "{ field: 'RolesAsString', operator: 'contains', value: '" + dataItem[i].Name + "'},"
        }
        filterCode += "]";

        //start filtering
        var dataSource = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid').dataSource;
        dataSource.filter({
            logic: "or",
            filters: filterCode
        });
    });
```

Even though `filterCode` gets correctly populated the filters do not reach the `DataSourceRequest request` parameter.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used push method for JS arrays to replace string composition of the filter:

```
$('#btnSearchRoles').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //process searched roles
        var multiselect = $("#RoleSubroleId").data("kendoMultiSelect");
        // get data items for the selected options.
        var dataItem = multiselect.dataItems();
        var setFilter = { logic: "or", filters: [] };
        for (var i = 0; i < dataItem.length; i++) {
            setFilter.filters.push({ field: "RolesAsString", operator: "contains", value: dataItem[i].Name });
        }

        //start filtering
        var dataSource = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid').dataSource;        
        dataSource.filter(setFilter);
    });
```